# MySQL: Calculate Remaining Selling Days in Month

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff, date-difference

I have a daily revenue goal calculation that states how much revenue I need to earn daily to achieve the monthly revenue goal:

```
'Revenue_Goal' / 'Selling_Days'
```

(Note: 'Selling_Days' is a whole already in the dataset.)

What I'm trying to accomplish is getting an adjusted daily goal based on how many days have passed. I PARTIALLY accomplished this with:

```
('Revenue_Goal' - SUM('Revenue')) / DATEDIFF(MAX('Date'),NOW())
```

However, the part that I can't figure out is only calculating selling days in the adjusted formula. I need to use the formula above (or something similar) that only counts days when:

- Monday to Friday = 1 Selling Day
- Saturday = 0.5 Selling Day
- Sunday = 0

So, if today is 3/25/16, my DATEDIFF calculation would return 6, but my goal is to get it to return 4.5.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is your table structure? You get the MAX of Date, what is in that column? It seems you already have something in your DB, it would be important to know what you already have. I guess you will also have the issue of bank holidays...

Comment: 'Date' is the day the revenue was acquired. MAX('Date') returns 31 for March 2016.

Comment: I don't really understand what this has to do with data stored in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense to write this as a stored function. I can think of three methods, each improving on the previous (though method 2 is probably good enough.)

**Method 1:** Start at first date, increment until second date. For each date, call DAYOFWEEK(). If Sunday then add 0, if Saturday add 0.5, otherwise add 1.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `count_days_goal`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `count_days_goal`(start_date DATE, end_date DATE) RETURNS FLOAT
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE sell_days FLOAT;
    DECLARE dow INT;

    SET sell_days = 0.0;
    WHILE start_date <= end_date DO
        SET dow = DAYOFWEEK(start_date);
        IF (dow > 1) THEN 
            IF (dow = 7) THEN SET sell_days = sell_days + 0.5;
            ELSE SET sell_days = sell_days + 1.0;
            END IF;
        END IF;
        SET start_date = start_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN (sell_days);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

A couple tests (note that my implementation includes the last day in the counted days):

```
select count_days_goal(DATE('2016-03-21'), DATE('2016-03-27'));
select count_days_goal(DATE('2016-03-01'), DATE('2016-03-27'));
```

This is straightforward but it's inefficient. It takes longer to run the further apart the days are. Mind you, one call will still be faster than an eyeblink, but it would be slightly offensive to most developers. Fortunately we can do better.

**Method 2:** Each full week is 5.5 selling days. So divide the number of days between the dates by 7, ignore the remainder for a moment, and multiple by 5.5.

Example: 32 days is (4 weeks + 4 days), which is 22 selling days plus 4 remainder.

That remainder is where things get tricky. Those 4 days might include a Saturday, or they might not. The easiest solution is to use method 1 for those last few days. It will never loop over more than 6 days so it's fast.

So now the code looks like this:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `count_days_goal`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `count_days_goal`(start_date DATE, end_date DATE) RETURNS FLOAT
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE sell_days FLOAT;
    DECLARE dow INT;
    DECLARE whole_weeks INT;

    SET whole_weeks = FLOOR(DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date)/7);
    SET start_date = start_date + (7 * whole_weeks);
    SET sell_days = whole_weeks * 5.5;

    WHILE start_date <= end_date DO
        SET dow = DAYOFWEEK(start_date);
        IF (dow > 1) THEN 
            IF (dow = 7) THEN SET sell_days = sell_days + 0.5;
            ELSE SET sell_days = sell_days + 1.0;
            END IF;
        END IF;
        SET start_date = start_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN (sell_days);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Method 3:** You can also use method 2 but rid of the loop entirely. To see how it might be done, it helps to have a calendar in front of you. (I didn't bother implementing this one; method 2 is quite good.)

Instead of looping, call `DAYOFWEEK` on the first and last dates. Let's call those `dow_start` and `dow_end`.

If `dow_start < dow_end` then those pesky remainder days all lie inside the week, they don't wrap around from Saturday back to Sunday. So all you need to do is:

```
SET answer = DATEDIFF(dow_end, dow_start) + 1;
IF dow_start = 1 (i.e. Sunday) THEN subtract 1 from answer
IF dow_end is 7 (i.e. Saturday) THEN subtract 0.5 from answer
```

If `dow_start > dow_end` then those pesky remainder days do wrap around. I believe in that case you can swap `dow_start` and `dow_end` (returning us to the previous case). Compute it as before, but then subtract the answer from 5.5 and add 1. (Explanation: count the days of week that are NOT between `day_start` and `day_end`, then subtract them from a week's total.)

Like I said I didn't write or test that one, so it may not be completely correct.

**How to handle bank holidays:** If you have them in a table you can simply `COUNT` the number of rows between the two dates. Subtract that from your answer. Easy! (Assuming the bank holidays are never on a weekend.) There are websites that list bank holidays for various countries, even one that will generate a list of dates for you far into the future, making it easy to build a holiday table.

Comment: Can you elaborate on Method 1? I'm really looking for something quick and dirty like that because it's just me (as a beginner MySQL user) who will be using these calculations and datasets.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. I wrote the first two methods as stored functions for you.

Answer (score 2):

This one of n ways to calc this

```
SELECT
  SUM( 
    ELT( DAYOFWEEK(CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m-'),nr)),
    '0','1','1','1','1','1','0.5') ) calc_days
FROM (
SELECT d2.a*10+d1.a  AS nr FROM (
  SELECT 0  a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 
  UNION ALL SELECT 
  5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8  UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS d1
  CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 0 a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3  ) AS d2
) AS x
WHERE nr BETWEEN  DAY(NOW()) AND DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW()))
ORDER BY nr;
```